# Adding SubMenu to Visual Studio Project Item Node

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

How can I add a menu and sub menu items when right click on a file item visual studio solution explorer?

I have one menu and three sub menu items which will be displayed when I right click on a file in solution explorer like the below picture.

I tried using .vsct buttons but it will display on context menu and Iam unable to add sub menus

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Authoring `VSCT` files is somewhat tricky; what you´ll need is a combination of a menu and buttons. First of all you need to reference the `IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE` group in your VSCT file.

```
<Group guid="guidCmdSet" id="grpIdMenuProjectItem" priority="0x0800">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE" />
</Group>
```

Than you create a new menu and add it to that group...

```
  <Menu guid="guidCmdSet" id="sampleMenu" type="Menu" priority="0x1000">
    <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="grpIdMenuProjectItem" />
    <CommandFlag>IconAndText</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Sample Menu</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>Sample Menu</CommandName>
    </Strings>
  </Menu>
```

For the submenu items another group is required, which will be added to the menu...

```
<Group guid="guidCmdSet" id="sampleMenuGroup" priority="0x1000">
    <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="sampleMenu"/>
</Group>
```

At least you define your submenu items using buttons and add them to the submenu group...

```
<Button guid="guidCmdSet" id="sampleMenuItem" priority="0x1000" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="sampleMenuGroup"/>
    <CommandFlag>TextOnly</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
        <ButtonText>Sample Menu Item 1</ButtonText>
        <CommandName>sampleMenuItem1</CommandName>
    </Strings>
</Button>
```

Don´t forget to define all symbols, otherwise the resource won´t compile.

```
<IDSymbol name="grpIdMenuProjectItem" value="0x1020"/>
<IDSymbol name="sampleMenu" value="0x1021"/>
<IDSymbol name="sampleMenuGroup" value="0x1022"/>
<IDSymbol name="sampleMenuItem" value="0x1023"/>
```

And this is what you get...

[image]

Comment: How can you add a command in the Document tab context menu. The menu where the "Pin Tab" is.

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras you should specify correct parent like this
      <Menu guid="guidMyPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenu" priority="0x1000" type="Menu">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_EZ_DOCWINDOWOPS"></Parent>
        <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>My menu</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Menu>