# VSCT menu items not showing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsct

Visual Studio 2019 16.5.0 preview 1.

I'm trying to get my menu items to show up either in a group or on a different menu.

Currently the menu items show up in the View/Other Windows menu on visual studio if I point them to IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1, but if I try to point them to MyMenuGroup, they just don't appear.  The code will run but the menu items never show up on the menu.  If I try to point the buttons to IDM_VS_MENU_EXTENSIONS, it won't even compile, giving the error below:

```
Undefined 'Parent/@id' attribute 'IDM_VS_MENU_EXTENSIONS' in a <Button> element
```

Below is my code:

```
<Groups>
  <Group guid="MyGroupMenuSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0100">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1" />
  </Group>
</Groups>

<Buttons>
  <Button guid="My_ExtVS2019PackageCmdSet" id="cmdidMyWindowCommand" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <!-- <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1" /> -->
    <Parent guid="MyGroupMenuSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>My Main Window</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
  <Button guid="My_ExtVS2019PackageCmdSet" id="cmdidMyOtherControlCommand" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <!--<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1" />-->
    <Parent guid="MyGroupMenuSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>My Other Window</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
</Buttons>
</Commands>

<Symbols>
  <!-- This is the package guid. -->
  <GuidSymbol name="My_ExtVS2019Package" value="{a28e16ed-f550-4cac-b087-f3728834a026}" />

  <GuidSymbol value="{3d62bd83-4a3e-4e04-8ea8-800ea9316e90}" name="My_ExtVS2019PackageCmdSet">
    <IDSymbol value="256" name="cmdidMyWindowCommand" />
    <IDSymbol value="257" name="cmdidMyOtherControlCommand" />
  </GuidSymbol>

  <GuidSymbol value="{dd7dd38d-bf53-408e-baa4-c5c7c7774f19}" name="MyGroupMenuSet">
    <IDSymbol value="4128" name="MyMenuGroup" />
    <IDSymbol value="256" name="cmdidCommand1" />
  </GuidSymbol>

</Symbols>
```

Any clue what's wrong with my code?

Comment: For `IDM_VS_MENU_EXTENSIONS`, i guess this is one issue about [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-menus?view=vs-2019#menus-on-the-visual-studio-menu-bar). I can reproduce same issue in my machine, and I'll report it later.

Comment: The MyMenuGroup is a group, and IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1 also represents a group. One group's parent should not be a group. You should add a menu into your vsct. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57215504/10910450).

Comment: @Lance-MSFT Thanks.  I figured it was just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently the menu items show up in the View/Other Windows menu on
>   visual studio if I point them to IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1.

Button's parent should be a `group` type. And `IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1` is one child group of [`IDG_VS_VIEW_DEV_WINDOWS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-menus?view=vs-2019#submenus-of-visual-studio-menus), so it works as we expected.

> But if I try to point them to MyMenuGroup, they just don't appear.

`MyMenuGroup` and `IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1` also represent `Group` type. One group's parent should be one menu instead of a group, or it won't work. See my another issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57215504/10910450).

So if you want to use your custom group, you should use this structure in `xx.vsct`:
`Button => MyMenuGroup(group) => one menu(menu) => IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1(group)`
  instead of:  `Button => MyMenuGroup(group) => IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1(group)`

**Workaround:**

Change this part:

```
    <Groups>
      <Group guid="MyGroupMenuSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0100">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1" />
      </Group>
    </Groups>
```

To:

```
    <!--<Groups>
      <Group guid="guidTestVSIXWindowPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1"/>
      </Group>
    </Groups>-->

    <Menus>
      <Menu guid="guidTestVSIXWindowPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenu" priority="0x0100" type="Menu">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_WNDO_OTRWNDWS1"/>
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>My Two Windows</ButtonText>
          <CommandName>MyTwoWindows</CommandName>
        </Strings>
      </Menu>
    </Menus>

    <Groups>
      <Group guid="guidTestVSIXWindowPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidTestVSIXWindowPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenu"/>
      </Group>
    </Groups>
```

And don't forget to define the `MyMenu` in `GuidSymbol` :

```
  <GuidSymbol value="{dd7dd38d-bf53-408e-baa4-c5c7c7774f19}" name="MyGroupMenuSet">
    <IDSymbol value="4128" name="MyMenuGroup" />
    <IDSymbol value="256" name="cmdidCommand1" />
    <IDSymbol name="MyMenu" value="41" />
  </GuidSymbol>
```

Then now VS can work to display your two windows in this way(View=>Other windows):

[image]

**In addition:** As for the Undefined `IDM_VS_MENU_EXTENSIONS`, I've post the feedback [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/4445). In my opinion, this could be one issue about the document or the build tools package, anyone interested in it can track the issue and get the latest info there.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks Lance.  Much appreciated.  I'll give this a go.